# Add custom jquery twitter feed to magento right column

Tags: jquery, magento, twitter

I really need help with Magento, I am failing to wrap my head around it!

Basically, I have a two column setup for my magento site, the right hand column is for a set of links and ads. All of these have been setup as static blocks and added to the catalog.xml file. Which I have done fine.

What I need to happen is somewhere in between these links, should be a titter feed. I have got the js for a twitter feed but I am finding it really difficult to add it in.

Considering I am very new with Magento could someone break it down for me, how to add a custom js script in the right hand column in between my already arranged static blocks. The js is jquery so presume I will need to include the 'noconflict' line. Again, how to make this happen would be good.

If it helps, this jquert twitter feed will stay on every page.

Thanks for any help given

Answer (score 0):

A custom module that includes your own template/layout files as well as your own custom Block class is probably the way to go.

You can attempt to do this with built-in tools, but the WYSIWYG editor may break your JS script since it will add/remove markup/code as it sees fit. Of course, you can always disable the WYSIWYG completely (makes it easier to work with, but clients like that thing).

In theory, you should be able to add this the same as you would add any other static block. If you are trying this and running into issues, perhaps it would be more beneficial if you described those issues in detail.

Comment: Thanks.I've not tried this, but basically in my xml file I have this;

<reference name="right">
     <block type="cms/block" name="rightlinkgallery">
       <action method="setBlockId"><id>rightlinkgallery</id></action>
     </block>
   <block type="cms/block" name="rightsidefacebook">
       <action method="setBlockId"><id>rightsidefacebook</id></action>
     </block>
   <block type="cms/block" name="rightlinkcontact">
       <action method="setBlockId"><id>rightlinkcontact</id></action>
     </block>
        </reference>

Comment: Ideally I would like to have a twitter feed after the first block (gallery). I dont know how to setup custom modules or how javascript can be added to them